# How to select MONTH() and YEAR() using SELECT query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Basically, I want to run a query to pull data entered into a VB form (specifically MONTH and YEAR).

This is what I currently have:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE MONTH(date_ordered) = ? AND YEAR(date_ordered) = ? ;
```

When I run this in my database, it doesn't work. I get no results.

However, if I put it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE MONTH(date_ordered) = 08 AND YEAR(date_ordered) = 1989;
```

It works fine and pulls the expected results. Obviously, as I am using a form where the user is supposed to input the 'month' and 'year' themselves, this makes things a bit tricky.

What am I missing here? Cheers for any thoughts.

Note: the date_ordered field is a Date/Time field with a Short Date format.

Comment: Decide what database you are using and tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Because those two products have different ways to do this...

Comment: Apologies; accident! Using SQL query for a MS Access database.

Comment: I dont see your problem. suppose you have a textbox for month called textBoxMonth than your sql would be "SELECT * from orders where MONTH(date_ordered) = " + textBoxMonth.Text

Comment: but using parameters would be much safer offcourse

Comment: Thanks for the help.

What I found was that if I entered '8' into the parameter box, then '1989' it worked - but if I enter '08' it does not. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE MONTH(date_ordered) = @mon and YEAR(date_ordered) = @year"
Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
        cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@mon", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox2.text
        Return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
End Using
```